# 1980's/1990's French comedy with a person who can't be captured in a photograph

Tags: identify-this-movie, comedy

I'm trying to recall a 1980's French comedy that I can't remember the name of. There are a couple of sub-plots in there:

- A husband and wife who fake their daughter's kidnapping and a clueless police inspector investigating the "crime"
- A woman whose hands were injured by one of the protagonists and he needs to take care of her
- A person who is so shy that he can't be photographed - but progresses gradually to where his outline is captured on film etc.
- One of the other protagonists is an "artistic" sex-obsessed person, who films ludicrous sexual encounters with his partners.

Answer (score 11):

This is the plot of [Zig Zag Story](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0086642/combined) from 1983.

> The lives of three Parisians - a color-blind painter, a radio show host and a perverted photographer - intertwine and go hilariously out of control. A classic cult comedy from the 80's.

Every single thing you mentioned is there; also memorable were its chain-reaction opening titles:

Comment: No problem. :) I like Rube Goldberg machines, so I remember that one. (For similarly bizarre opening credits, see [Superman III](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P9BwmdEfrDk).)